# Finding last part of Laurent series in annulus

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Find the Laurent series in given annulus:

I have function in annulus $1<|z-1|<2$, $${1 \over {z(z-3)^2}}$$

After splitting function into partial fractions, I got the first two sums, but stacked in last one

$${1\over 3(z-3)^2}$$ What should i do for that?

Any help or advice are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that$$\frac1{3(z-3)^2}=\frac13(z-3)^{-2}=\frac13\left(\frac1{3-z}\right)'.$$So, compute the Laurent series of $\dfrac1{3-z}$ and differentiate it termwise.

Comment: Thanks, and one more question sir, how can i know for my $ 1<|z−1|<2$ annulus, I need to take ${1 \over 3}{1 \over {1-{z \over 3}}}$ or $-{1 \over z}{1 \over {1-{3 \over z}}}$

Comment: Neither:\begin{align}\frac1{3-z}&=\frac1{2-(z-1)}\\&=\frac12\cdot\frac1{1-\frac{z-1}2}\\&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{z-1}2\right)^n.\end{align}

Comment: Yes I mean by looking to given annulus, how to decide which one i need to take?

Comment: I took this one because, since $\left|\frac{z-1}2\right|<1$, the series converges.